# How to close database connection in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When i am closing database connection in **node.js** i am getting this error

`Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit`.

Here is my **code**

```
socket.on('adminConnect', function (email) {
    connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config); // db_config has all details of database
    connection.connect(); // no problem in connection
    connection.query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE  email = '" + email + "' ", function (err, results, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (results[0]) {
            // Some code
            connection.end(); // its giving error "Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit."
        } else {
            console.log("no id");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Usually, you don't want to create a new connection for every request. Keep the connection for more additional queries.

Comment: Alright i will do this. But my problem is where to end the connection?

Comment: @user the point is you don't. Why would you close a connection you can reuse instead? Connections are cheap but opening them takes a round trip or three.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you reuse connections instead of opening/closing all the time.

To answer your question, this is how:

```
connection.end();
```

Try putting the line outside the callback, because all the queries must complete before ending a connection, so you're safe like this:

```
connection.query(.......);
connection.end();
```

Your code would then be:

```
socket.on('adminConnect', function (email) {
    connection = mysql.createConnection(db_config); // db_config has all details of database
    connection.connect(); // no problem in connection
    connection.query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE  email = '" + email + "' ", function (err, results, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (results[0]) {
            // Some code
        } else {
            console.log("no id");
        }
    });
    connection.end();
});
```

Comment: This answer is correct if i don't have to use connection anymore. If i have to reuse it, it need not to be closed. Thanks randunel.

Comment: You're not waiting for `connection.query` to be completed before you call `connection.end`. It should be called from within the `connection.query` callback.

Comment: @robertklep If you had taken the time to browse the documentation before making wrong assumptions, you would have noticed that you may call `.end()` before the callback is triggered, because `Closing the connection is done using end() which makes sure all remaining queries are executed before sending a quit packet to the mysql server.` - quote from the node-mysql documentation. There is an example in the docs with a similar code. https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#introduction . Regarding reusing the connection, read the first paragraph from my answer ;)

Comment: @randunel I am truly sorry, you are indeed correct! My assumption was based on the general idea with Node that you have to wait for actions to be performed before you close connections etc, and the MySQL is smart with that respect. So again, sorry!